# Avoid session expires after transaction.commit in pyramind paster pshell

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, paster

Seems `tansaction.commit()` is the only way I have to make a commit in pyramid `paster pshell`.
I understand it's good in serving webpages but in shell, after that, on next SQLAlchemy MyModel.my_attribute call I get:

```
DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <MyModel at 0x9394d0c> is not bound to
a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'my_attribute' cannot proceed
```

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `keep_session=True` to `ZopeTransactionExtension()`

Source: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.sqlalchemy#long-lasting-session-scopes

Comment: Wow, 2 years later, I don't even have the chance to test it anymore, good to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the `expire_on_commit` option to the SQLA session. Once you perform a commit, the objects you were using with the old transaction must be refreshed or merged into the new session. The point is that this is not actually related to the `transaction` module itself.

Comment: This did not happen (I'm quite sure but can't check now) in Pylons' `paster shell` where I could use `Session.commit()` then use objects again with no `DetachedInstanceError`. Now I cannot use it anymore and I'm invited to use `transaction.commit()`, moreover I should pass `expire_on_commit` to `sessionmaker` which is the one in my `models.py` as `sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension())` and changing it would reflect on served pages too. So, what can I do (beside not using `transaction` anymore)?

Comment: moreover adding `expire_on_commit = False` to `sessionmaker` does not change things: in `pshell` since, after `transaction.commit()`, I get `DetachedInstanceError` anyway... sob